# Can not see progress on Progress bar in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-progressbar, android-toast

On button click I am calling openChannel function

fetchXML is a thread which downloads xml and sets variables. Though it takes 2-5 seconds to load new view I can see progressbar jump from 0 to 100 directly.

Also Toast in openchannel ... it loads only after new view is loaded i.e. after loadView ... which breaks the purpose for what it was written.

Toast should run before showNews() but it is getting executed after it !!!!

Why it is getting delayed ?
Any help aprreciated.

UPDATE :

HandleXML.java

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

public class HandleXML
{
   private List<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
   private List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
   private int totalNews = 0;

   private String urlString = null;
   private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = null;
   public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;

   public HandleXML(String url)
   {
      this.urlString = url;
   }

   public List<String> getTitle()
   {
      return title;
   }
   public List<String> getDescription()
   {
      return description;
   }

   public int getTotalNews()
   {
       return totalNews;
   }

   public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) 
   {
      int event;
      String text=null;
      boolean isItem = false, isTitle = false;

      try 
      {
         event = myParser.getEventType();
         while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && totalNews < 10) 
         {
             String name=myParser.getName();
             switch (event)
             {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:   
                    if(name.equals("item"))
                    {
                        isItem = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:    
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    text = text.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if(name.equals("title") && isItem)
                    {
                        title.add(text);
                        isItem = false;
                        isTitle = true;
                    }
                    else if(name.equals("description") && isTitle)
                    {
                        description.add(text);
                        totalNews++;
                        isTitle = false;
                    }
                    break;
             }       
             event = myParser.next(); 
         }
         parsingComplete = false;

      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public void fetchXML()
   {
       Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() 
           {
              try 
              {
                 URL url = new URL(urlString);
                 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                 conn.connect();                 
                 InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                 xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                 XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
                 myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                 myparser.setInput(stream, null);
                 parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                 stream.close();
              } 
              catch (Exception e) 
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
          });
      thread.start(); 
   }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private int titleIds[] = {R.id.news1,R.id.news2,R.id.news3,R.id.news4,R.id.news5,R.id.news6,R.id.news7,R.id.news8,R.id.news9,R.id.news10};  
    private int descIds[] = {R.id.desc1,R.id.desc2,R.id.desc3,R.id.desc4,R.id.desc5,R.id.desc6,R.id.desc7,R.id.desc8,R.id.desc9,R.id.desc10};  
    private int colorIds[] = {R.color.DarkSalmon,R.color.DarkCyan,R.color.CornflowerBlue,R.color.BlueViolet,R.color.Goldenrod,R.color.Orchid,R.color.IndianRed,R.color.MediumAquamarine,R.color.LightCoral,R.color.Teal};

    private ProgressBar progress;
    private HandleXML obj = null;

    private int currCnt = 0;
    private int rand_color = new Random().nextInt(10);
    private int rand_color2 = new Random().nextInt(10);
    private boolean inMain = true, inChannel = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        findViewById(R.id.newsScroll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.newsChannels).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progress.setMax(100);

    }

    public void showNews(String url)
    {       
        currDesc = null;    
        currTitle = null;
        obj = null;

        progress.setProgress(30);
        System.out.println("30 : "+new Date());

        rand_color = new Random().nextInt(10);
        rand_color2 = new Random().nextInt(10);

        if(rand_color == rand_color2 && rand_color == 9)
            rand_color2 = 0;
        else if(rand_color == rand_color2)
            rand_color2 = rand_color+1;

        obj = new HandleXML(url);
        obj.fetchXML();    

        progress.setProgress(50);  

        while(obj.parsingComplete);

        progress.setProgress(70);

        if(obj.getTitle().size() >0 && obj.getDescription().size() >0)
        {
            List<String> title = obj.getTitle();
            List<String> description = obj.getDescription();


            for(int i=0; i<obj.getTotalNews(); i++)
            {
                Button twT = (Button) findViewById(titleIds[i]);
                twT.setText(title.get(i).trim());
                twT.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(colorIds[rand_color])));

                Button twD = (Button) findViewById(descIds[i]);
                twD.setText(description.get(i).trim());
                twD.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("AHL NEWS ALERT")
              .setMessage("FAILED TO LOAD NEWS !!")
              .setCancelable(false)
              .setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      dialog.cancel();
                  }
              });
              AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
              alert.show();
        }

        progress.setProgress(90);
    }

    public void openChannel(View view)
    {       
        progress.setProgress(10);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading Please Wait ... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        showNews("http://example.com/news.xml");

        progress.setProgress(100);

        findViewById(R.id.newsScroll).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.newsChannels).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.newsScroll).scrollTo(0, 0);

        inMain = false;
        inChannel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `fetchXML` is using a Thread then that's how it should work. You set the progress to 10 and then call loadNews which calls `fetchXML` in which there is a Thread.
It takes only a fraction of second to create a Thread for you.

I suggest you use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which give you more control over the process of fetching and parsing the xml. You should update your ProgressBar from inside the AsyncTask. There two method for this. One is [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate) and the other would be [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)).

Comment: Understood the progressbar situation but what about Toast. It should be shown immediately. Why it gets visible only after url is downloaded and views are prepared ?

Comment: @user2952821 can't really say why without seeing the full code.